# How to use different tables for entity on runtime using JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am building a COTs product which records sales data. Since it will be used by different business owners i want to save the sales data to the owner specific tables. So how do i use a single entity to perform operation on different tables based on unique owner id? My core object and business logic is the same. I am just stuck on how to persist data for each owner in a separate tables. I don't want to have it all in one table with owner id as unique. It just creates risk of impacting all the clients data while any update/migration to the table.

Comment: What you're asking about is called "multi-tenancy". There are a number of options available to deal with it, and a search on that term should provide you with useful information. (These days, running separate instances for different business customers is probably the easiest/cheapest option.)

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Will get back if find problem in implementation.